# Google SignIn In Cognito Using Custom Login Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Currently, I am trying to implement **Social Login** for my web Application using **Cognito Aws Service**. But I don't want to redirect the user to Cognito **Hosted UI** for Social Login.

So I use [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) for the Google Login and I am getting the callback access token too

```
<GoogleLogin
   clientId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
   buttonText="Login"
   onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
   onFailure={this.responseGoogleFailure}
   cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
/>


responseGoogle = async (response) => {
  console.log("response..........", response);
  const user = {
    name: response.profileObj.name,
    email: response.profileObj.email
  };

  let expires_at = 3600 * 1000 + new Date().getTime()

  Auth.federatedSignIn('google', { token: response.tokenId, expires_at }, user).then(credentials => {
     console.log(credentials);
  });
}
```

The above code gives the Cognito session values but that doesn't create a user in the user pool.

I have search a lot but didn't find any solutions. I have already referred this below links it refers to my problem. Basically I don't want to use hosted UI for the SocialLogin.

*Thank In advance*

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1316

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3875

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to open the link directly to the Google login page without showing the hosted ui but still have the authentication go through Cognito, you basically link directly to the url which is opened when you select the Google button in the Cognito hosted ui i.e.

```
https://<YOUR_DOMAIN>.auth.<REGION>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Google&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=TOKEN&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=openid
```

You will end up back at your redirect uri after the auth and the user will have been created/authenticated.

Comment: How do you find out which link to open. Do I have to create a hosted UI and inspect it?